# Where should I be updating filtered data, in saga, reselect or reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, reselect

I'm currently using `reselect`, `redux-sagas` and reducers. I have a filterParameter in state which holds filteredParameter values `filterReducer.js`:

```
initialState = {
  filteredParameters: { ... } // null by default
}
```

The filtered data is used in my component `filters.js`:

```
// On change function
  const statusChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setFilterParameters({ ...filterParameters, [name]: parseInt(value) });
  };

// Render
 {statuses && (
        <select name="statusId" onChange={statusChange}>
          <option>All</option>
          {statuses.map(status => (
            <option
              selected={
                filteredParameters && filteredParameters.statusId === status.id
              }
              key={status.id}
              name={status.name}
              value={status.id}
            >
              {status.icon} {status.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      )}

// MapDispatchToProps
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  filterIdeas: parameters => dispatch(filterIdeas(parameters)),
  fetchCategories: () => dispatch(fetchCategoriesStart())
});
```

Then I have a `saga` setup to catch this action in `filter.sagas.js`:

```
function* filterCurrentIdeas({ payload: filteredParameters }) {
  try {
    yield put(setFilterParameters(filteredParameters));
    const ideas = yield select(selectBoardIdeasItems);

    // Custom function that does the filtering handling, this is shown below 

    const filterResults = yield call(
      filterIdeasByStatus,
      ideas,
      filteredParameters
    ); 
    yield put(filterIdeasSuccess(filterResults)); // This then gets fed into the reducer
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
}
```

Here's my reducer `filter.reducer.js`

```
    case BoardActionTypes.FILTER_IDEAS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredItems: action.payload
      };
```

Here's the custom utility helper for filtering `filter.utils.js`:

```
export const filterIdeasByStatus = (ideas, filter) => {
  const { statusId, categoryId, orderBy, query } = filter;
  const orderedIdeas = orderBy ? _.orderBy(ideas, ["voteCount"]) : ideas;
  const regex = new RegExp(`${query}`, "gmius");

  const filtered = orderedIdeas.filter(
    idea =>
      (!statusId || (statusId && idea.IdeaStatus.id === statusId)) &&
      (!categoryId ||
        (categoryId && _.includes(idea.categoryIds, categoryId))) &&
      (!query || (query && idea.title.match(regex)))
  );

  return convertIdeasToObject(filtered);
};
```

Currently this all works, but am I doing this wrong or is there a much better approach or guide out there that can give me a better example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The helper function `filterIdeasByStatus` is a great practice to keep your code modular and organized.

However, given `setFilterParameters` is an action:

`setFilterParameters({ ...filterParameters, [name]: parseInt(value) });`

Why are you calling it twice?

1. At `filter.sagas.js` in `filterCurrentIdeas` saga
2. At `filters.js` component

Usually you will want to dispatch an action on `statusChange` and let the saga filter the items (as you did). But calling the same action twice might cause side effects.

Meticulous Tip: Mind that React component namespace are usually capitalized, i.e filters.js should be Filters.js.

You also can seek for best practices and/or ask for feedback in [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Hope you gained few insights :)